# How to redirect stdout and stderr to echo command?

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I am trying to redirect standard output and standard error to echo command.

```
echo $(python --version) 1>&2 // prints in stderr
```

and

```
echo $(python3 --version) 1>&2 // Python 3.6.9
```

I try to run this command in java. I need to capture both python 2 and 3 version in stdout.

How can I pass both stderr and stdout to echo command?

Comment: Just like this echo `$(python --version)`

Comment: It appears to be working fine (prints in terminal). But actually it redirects to stderr. When executing the command in java, output available in stderr not in stdout.